# regex websphere file with php

Tags: php, regex, websphere

i'm trying to create a regular expression for this kind of log:

> [9/23/11 11:09:53:632 CEST] 0000005b FormLoginExte 3   Form based login: userid/password present in the form. User is: user1

i've created this:

> preg_match("/^[\d+/\d+/\d+\ \d+:\d+:\d+:\d+\ CEST]\ \w{8}\ \w+?\ +\w+?\ +.+?$", $line, $matches); // pattern to format the line

and get this error:

> [9/21/11 12:11:03:126 CEST] 0000004d FormLoginExte 3 Form based login: userid/password present in the form. User is: user1
>   Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '\' in C:\AppServ\www\logWebsphere\logWebspere.php on line 79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using forward slashes as your delimeter but are also including unescaped forward slashes in your regex.  You should escape them first by preceding them with a two backslashes.  Two backslashes are required because the backslash is itself a meta character and must be escaped by using a second backslash.  This in effect creates one backslash which can be used to escape the delimeter.

So your regex becomes:

`preg_match("/^[\d+\\/\d+\\/\d+\ \d+:\d+:\d+:\d+\ CEST]\ \w{8}\ \w+?\ +\w+?\ +.+?$/", $line, $matches);`

Please note you were also missing a delimiter.

Additionally, you could simply change delimters, like so:

`preg_match("~^[\d+\/\d+\/\d+\ \d+:\d+:\d+:\d+\ CEST]\ \w{8}\ \w+?\ +\w+?\ +.+?$~", $line, $matches);`

**Edit**

I've just noticed that you are trying to match `[` and `]` as literals.  These, however, are meta characters (character classes) and should, I believe, also be escaped( `\[` and `\]`).

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions (preg_match) are slower than running a simple:

```
<?php
$data = explode(" ","[9/23/11 11:09:53:632 CEST] 0000005b FormLoginExte 3 Form based login: userid/password present in the form. User is: user1");

//data now contains all the info that you need
var_dump($data);
?>
```

POC here: http://codepad.org/nmo90QlI